# evolute of an astroid is another astroid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, plane-geometry, plane-curves

I want to prove that the evolute of the astroid, $(a\cos^3{t},a\sin^3{t})$, $t \in [0,2\pi)$, is another astroid turned by a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle.

I have tried a variable change from the parametric equation of $t=r-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle turn but I can´t get an equation of the following form: $$(b\cos^3{r},b\sin^3{r})$$

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Perhaps there's only a small step that you have to take to finish the calculation.

Comment: Yes, in the future please include all details of your computations. We can't read minds.

Answer (score 0):

The rotated astroid, twice the given one, has parametric equations
$$\left\{\sqrt{2} a\cos ^3 t-\sqrt{2} a\sin ^3 t,\sqrt{2}a\sin ^3 t+\sqrt{2} a\cos ^3 t\right\}$$
Because the rotation matrix is
$$R(\pi/4)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In the picture below the graph for $a=1$

---

[image]