# Prove that the evolute of an astroid is another astroid using formulas.

Tags: calculus

Prove that the evolute of an astroid is another astroid using formulas.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. If you show your attempt, we could help finding the mistake in your proof and try to fix it!

Comment: there are several computational mistakes. For instance, $\frac{d}{dt}\cos^3(t) = -3\cos^2(t)\sin(t)$, and not $-3\cos^2(t)$.

Comment: But then, it's full of typos. The formula for $c''$ doesn't match. Also, that's a bad idea to use $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for both the first astroid and its evolute

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. You should still not call the coordinates of the evolute $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ though.

Comment: There is an error in your computation of $x'^2 + y'^2$: this should be nonnegative but you end up with something negative at $t=-\pi/4$ for instance

Comment: This would be $\sqrt{x'^2+y^2}$, not $x'^2+y'^2$. Also, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute), there is a mistake in your formula for $b$: this should be a "+" and not a "-" after your $\sin^3(t)$

Comment: To be more precise,  you should have $x'^2 + y'^2 = 9\cos^2\sin^2$

Comment: Now, use $\sin^2 = 1  -\cos^2$ and you should get the right answer. Instead of editing your question, you may write an answer below detailing your mistake and showing the right computations

Comment: Notation: use `x''` (2 copies of `'` character) for double-prime $x''$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957224/evolute-of-an-astroid-is-another-astroid) with a graph

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in the final calculation of the $x$-coordinate of the evolute. (Note: In what follows, I'm suppressing explicit dependence on $t$ where it's unambiguous, writing $x$ for $x(t)$, etc.)
$$
(x')^2 + (y')^2 = 9 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t 
$$
and
$$
x' y'' - x'' y' = -9 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t,  
$$
the coordinates of the evolute simplify to
$$
\left\{
\begin{align} 
a &= x + y' \\
b &= y - x' 
\end{align}
\right.
$$
After substituting explicit expressions for $t$, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{align} 
a &= 3\cos t - 2\cos^3 t \\
b &= 3\sin t - 2\sin^2 t 
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Why is this **also** the equation of an astroid? [The graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tanwgbnhxn) seems to show that the evolute is a copy of the original astroid rotated by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and scaled by a factor of $2$. In other words, using the standard formulas for rotation and noting that
$$
\sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 
$$
we would like to show that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align} 
u &= 2 \cdot \frac{x - y}{\sqrt{2}} \\
v &= 2 \cdot \frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
\right.
$$
parametrizes the evolute.

However, *this doesn't work,* as you can check by substituting in the formulas for $x$ and $y$ and noting that the resulting $(u, v)$ does not equal the parametrization $(a, b)$ calculated before.

The problem is that in the rotated coordinates, we need to shift the parameter, so that each $t$ corresponds to the same point on the evolute astroid as the original one. For example, at $t=0$, we have the point $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ right in the middle of one of the curving sides of the original astroid, but the corresponding point on the evolute (center of the osculating circle) comes out to the cusp $(a, b) = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$. If we intend to recover this evolute curve via transformations of the original astroid, we need to $t=0$ to correspond to the cusp.

Hence, the formulas that we should verify look like:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align} 
a(t) &= 2 \cdot 
\frac{x\bigr(t-\frac\pi4\bigr) - y\bigr(t-\frac\pi4\bigr)}{\sqrt{2}} \\
b(t) &= 2 \cdot 
\frac{x\bigr(t-\frac\pi4\bigr) + y\bigr(t-\frac\pi4\bigr)}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
\right.
$$

You should expand each of these expressions and check that they indeed recover the formulas for $a$ and $b$ above!